# CompositeView with Collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, marionette

*** UPDATE: RESOLVED, PLEASE SCROLL DOWN ***

With the below, the list renders, but no rows are rendered. This is because I don't define the collection inside the composite view.

If I do put: collection: new Users in list.js then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
        return parent.apply(this, arguments);
      } has no method 'on'
```

in backbone.js: line 203, which is:

```
// An inversion-of-control version of `on`. Tell *this* object to listen to
    // an event in another object ... keeping track of what it's listening to.
    listenTo: function (obj, name, callback) {
      var listeners = this._listeners || (this._listeners = {});
      var id = obj._listenerId || (obj._listenerId = _.uniqueId('l'));
      listeners[id] = obj;
      obj.on(name, typeof name === 'object' ? this : callback, this);
      return this;
    },
```

**Views**

row.js

```
define([
  'marionette',
  'text!app/views/templates/user/row.html'
],
  function (Marionette, Template) {
    "use strict"

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: Template,
      tagName: 'tr'
    })

  })
```

list.js

```
define([
  'marionette',
  'text!app/views/templates/user/list.html',
  'app/collections/users',
  'app/views/user/row'
],
  function (Marionette, Template, Users, User) {
    "use strict"


    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({


      template: Template,
      itemView: User,
      itemViewContainer: "tbody",


    })
  })
```

**This has been resolved by doing this:**

user/list.js

```
define([
  'marionette',
  'text!app/views/templates/user/list.html',
  'app/collections/users',
  'app/views/user/row'
],
  function (Marionette, Template, Users, User) {
    "use strict"

    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
      template: Template,
      itemView: User,
      itemViewContainer: "tbody",
      initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Users()
        this.collection.fetch()
      }
    })
  })
```

user/row.js

```
define([
  'marionette',
  'text!app/views/templates/user/row.html'
],
  function (Marionette, Template) {
    "use strict"

    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: Template,
      tagName: "tr"
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are

1. Passing a collection *instance* to the composite view? I.e. `new Users()`
2. Fetching the data to display with a `fetch()` on the collection?